# Solvable subgroups in $GL(n,F)$

Tags: group-theory

Is it true, that any solvable subgroup $G$ in $GL(n,F)$ is subgroup of upper triangular matrix in some basis?

Comment: If sombody know answer "yes", or "no", post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $F$ is algebraically closed and the group is connected ( and algebraic)  then the answer is yes. This is Borel's theorem -- the search  term is Borel subgroup.

However, we need connected,  even for $F$ algebraically closed (@Derek Holt: thanks for pointing the example of finite solvable groups ) Indeed, any (solvable) non-abelian finite group has an irreducible representation of $\dim>1$, say $\dim n$ so take the image of that group in $GL(n,F)$.

For  $F = \mathbb{R}$, you have an abelian subroup $SO(2,\mathbb{R})\subset GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ that is not upper triangular in any basis.

Also note: any finite subgroup of the subgroup of upper triangular matrices  is abelian if $\text{char} F=0$.

If $F$ is moreover algebraically closed then abelian groups are included in a conjugate of the upper triangular matrices.

It's related to whether all the irreducible finite representations over $F$ of a given group are of dimension $1$.

Comment: But $S_4 < {\rm GL}(3,{\mathbb C})$ cannot be upper triangularized.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Oops, it has to be connected, sorry, I will correct that. Thanks!

Comment: @DerekHolt: If $\text{char} F=0$ then any finite subgroup of the upper triangular matrices is included in a conjugate of the diagonal matrices and therefore abelian. There is no torsion in the unipotent part.

Comment: You need a *faithful* irreducible representation, not just an irreducible representation.

Comment: @Kenta S: Thank you for your feedback, I will look into it!

Answer (score 6):

The group of upper triangular matrices over any field has a nilpotent normal subgroup (the unipotent matrices) with abelian quotient group. So any solvable group that does not have that property, such as $S_4$, can never be conjugate to an upper triangular group.